# Problem with try/catch block - Integer between (0-9) console program

Tags: c++, try-catch

I am having a problem running the code I have put below.
All I need to do is have a user input an integer then save it to my cNumber variable.

then assign the value of subtracting the ASCII value of `zero` from cNumber to the variable iNumber and test it in a try/catch block and cout the results of multiplying the valid (0-9) integer by 2.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declare variables 
char cNumber;
int iNumber;

int main () {
  // Begin infinite while loop
  while (1) {
    // Prompt user to enter aa number within th range of (0-9)
    cout << "Please enter an number between 0 and 9: ";

    //Get character from the keyboard and validate it as integer 
    //within the range (0-9)
    try {
      //Assign user input alue into cNumber variable
      cin >> cNumber;

      //Subtract ASCII value of zero from cNumber and assign to iNumber 
      iNumber = cNumber - 48;
      if (iNumber < 0) {
        throw string(cNumber + " is not within the range of (0-9)");
      }
      if (iNumber > 9) {
        throw string(cNumber + " is not within the range of (0-9)");
      }
    }
    catch (exception ex) {
      cerr << cNumber + " is not a valid selection.... Input Error" << endl;
    }
    cout << "The result is " + iNumber * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles, but I'm not clear what you want it to do.

Comment: exceptions should be caught by const reference

Comment: @Sam Miller: +1 from me on that, You should put that in a answer, also the perils of not doing so, its an important point & will make a great answer. i.e. If OP does clarify what he actually needs!

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you're asking, but I'll take a potshot at a few of your problems.

The expression `cNumber + " is not within the range of (0-9)"` is addition between `char` and `char const*`, which is not valid. You're probably accidentally manipulating pointer addresses.

It *is* possible to concatenate a `char` to a string, but it has to be an actual `std::string` object.

So:

```
throw cNumber + string(" is not within the range of (0-9)");
```

Similarly, you're misusing `+` later in your code.

Write:

```
cerr << cNumber << " is not a valid selection.... Input Error" << endl;
```

You're also throwing `std::string` but catching `std::exception`. Strings do not derive from exceptions. Read the chapter in your C++ book about try/catch. (Throwing/catching strings is not recommended anyway, and neither is catching by value.)

Also, if the input is not numeric, the extraction into `int` will fail... but you have no error checking/resetting on the `cin` stream.

For each line of your code, take a look at each component of it and ask yourself, "what does this do? Why did I write this?" If, for any piece of code, you cannot answer and *prove* the answer to these two questions, stop and think about whether or not it's correct.

Comment: Also, the last statement is outside the try...catch block, so it's executed even when the user enters an non-digit.

Comment: @MRAB: That's a higher-level logic issue, rather than an actual failure in writing code. Let's leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing a `std::string`, but your catch block is declared as having a `std::exception` parameter.

Don't know if this mismatch could be the root of your problem.

In any case, it is not advisable to throw `std::string`, since this class can throw exceptions,and if and exception is thrown while handling a previous exception, big trouble (sudden termination).

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly complex to me why not just:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  // Begin infinite while loop
    while (1) 
    {
        // Prompt user to enter aa number within th range of (0-9)
        cout << "Please enter an number between 0 and 9: ";

        // Get character from the keyboard and validate it as integer within the range (0-9)
        // Assign user input value into cNumber variable
        char cNumber;
        cin >> cNumber;

        // Subtract ASCII value of zero from cNumber and assign value to iNumber variable
        int iNumber = cNumber - 48;

        if (iNumber < 0 || iNumber > 9)
        {
            cerr << cNumber << " is not within the range of (0-9)" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The result is " + iNumber * 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it! I appreciate everyones input a ton... I apologize for my inexperience... I am currently one week into my C++ class right now.

Comment: @Mike Stewart, don't apologize for inexperience. There's no need for that. SO needs both experienced and inexperienced programmers.